# Can tau decay into a pair of charm and strange quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, leptons

I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_(particle)) that tau can decay to hadrons made of quarks and it seems like a tau can only decay to a pair of down and anti-up quarks. I understand that tau (1.8GeV) doesn't have enough mass for anti-top (173 GeV) and bottom quarks but it seems okay for anti-charm (1.2 GeV) and strange (<1 GeV) quarks. Is it really possible?

[image]

Comment: apparently possible. It will strictly be one anti-charm one strange with other by-products, and very rare occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you don't just need to make the anti-charm and strange quarks (with their Higgs-given masses), you also need to provide enough energy that they can form hadrons - bound states that actually exist. The lightest boundstates with charm quarks are the D mesons, which have a mass of $1.9\text{ GeV}$. So the final state cannot involve charm quarks.

However, strange quarks can form Kaons, which have masses around $0.5\text{ GeV}$. So that should be fine. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9503474.pdf) seems to calculate things like decay rates from Taus into Kaons.

If this involves the $W^-$ turning into a strange and an anti-up, it is "Cabibo suppressed." The $W^-\rightarrow s+\bar{u}$ vertex has a factor of $V_{us}\approx0.2$. Then the process is proportional to this CKM matrix element squared $\sim 0.04$. So probably most of the time the formation of Kaons from a Tau should be imagined as the $W^-$ turns into an anti-up and a down, then those hadronize into two kaons (hadronization cannot change the total strangeness of the state). So I guess I'd be in support of Wikipedia's statement that the Tau pretty much only decays into $d+\bar{u}$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand why all the energy required to form a hadron has to come from a single the tau lepton. D has mass larger than tau but only "half" of D (charm quark) is contributed by tau. Other reactions might generate the other "half". So in total, the formation of D can be contributed to a tau decay and something else.

Comment: @LL I admit that I don't have the explanation fully at hand. Hadronization is conceptually difficult. But it is true that all the particles formed in the decay have to get their mass from the tau if we're talking about what the tau decays into; where else can they get it from? On long timescales (longer than hadronization timescale), one should think of the tau as decaying to a kaon and a pion, not just a strange and an anti-up (for example). It's not feasible to have something else occur (like another nearby collision?) within the hadronization timescale to give "the rest of the hadron."

Comment: @LL Consider this - if a decaying particle isn't responsible for the energy used to hadronize, then the muon should be able to decay into $d\bar{u}$ that then hadronize into pions. But the muon ONLY decays into one thing - an electron and two neutrinos. But anyway... the decaying particle _is_ responsible for the energy used to hadronize. Energy is conserved in the universe - it can't come from nowhere.

Comment: @L L  " D has mass larger than tau but only "half" of D (charm quark) is contributed by tau"; what do you mean by this? Are you talking about coupling or decay?

Answer (score 0):

The process linking $\tau$ lepton with the $c$ and $s$ quarks exists, but can only go in one direction.

Indeed, the $D^-_s$ meson (the lightest meson made of $c$ and $s$ quarks) decays to $\tau^- \bar{\nu}_\tau$ with probability of [about 5%](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/BranchingRatio.action?desig=89&parCode=S034&home=MXXX040).
Similarly, the $D^-$ meson made of $c$ and $d$ quarks can also decay [(rarely)](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/BranchingRatio.action?desig=247&parCode=S031&home=MXXX035) into $\tau^- \bar{\nu}_\tau$ .

The opposite (under [crossing symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_(physics))) process, $\tau^- \to D^-_{(s)} \nu_\tau$, is forbidden kinematically as the summed mass of the final state particles is larger than the mass of the initial state.